# Using Scss variables in Nuxt3 within components

Tags: sass, nuxt3

I am declaring variables in scss files and want to access them within Nuxt3 components. The code in the scss file works, but I cannot access the variable from a component file.

Example :

_all-abstract.scss :

```
$color-blue : #020D78;
```

component.vue :

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Hello !</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<style lang="scss">
// @import '@/assets/styles/scss/abstracts/_all-abstracts.scss';

h1 {
  color:$color-blue;

}</style>
```

nuxt.config :

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  modules:['@nuxtjs/style-resources'],
    css: ['@/assets/styles/scss/style.scss'],
    vite: {
        css: {
            preprocessorOptions: {
                sass: {
                    additionalData: ['@import "@/assets/styles/scss/abstracts/_all-abstracts.scss";']
                },
            },
        },

    },
});
```

The SCSS code from the _all-abstracts.scss file is taken into account, but I cannot call the variable in the component.

So far, the only workaround I found was to manually import the scss file at the beginning of the module, but this is not very convenient for projects with a lot of component.

Note that Sass-loader and style-resources are installed.

Any thoughts on how to make the scss handling more fluid here ?

Thank you !